# Check if labels are empty, stay or send data to database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using PHP, HTML5, and JavaScript.

I am making a webpage (which will be linked to a database). And I am trying to check if the labels have input in them, which works, but it will go to the next page and send data when the button is clicked even when there is **no** input in the labels.

You're supposed to stay on the page until input in all labels. It also gives an error message which works.

Is there something I can insert into my javascript, so it goes to the next page *and* send the data (like method="GET")

I have never linked a database to a website before, so I don't know how to send the data only when all input fields are filled.

This is my HTML5 code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="assets-addperson/css/personstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Festive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Add a person</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pagesize">
            <h1>Create a new account</h1>
            <img src="assets-addperson/images/create_account.png" alt="create_account" class="image_account"/>

            <p class="text_labels_complete">Every field needs to be filled!</p>

            <!--<form action="personadded.php" method="GET">-->
                <div class="class-labels">
                    <label for="input-firstname">
                        First Name
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="input-firstname" name="firstname">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="input-name">
                        Name
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="input-name" name="name">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="input-gender">
                        Gender
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="input-gender" name="gender">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="input-description">
                        Description
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="input-description" name="description">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" class="create_account_button" value="Create Account">
            <!--</form>-->
        </div>
        <script src="assets-addperson/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the current javascript code I have

```
console.log("loaded");

var buttonElement = document.querySelector(".create_account_button");
var labelElementLabelsComplete = document.querySelector(".text_labels_complete");

var inputFirstname;
var inputName;
var inputGender;
var inputDescription;

buttonElement.addEventListener("click",function()
{
    inputFirstname = document.querySelector("#input-firstname").value;
    inputName = document.querySelector("#input-name").value;
    inputGender = document.querySelector("#input-gender").value;
    inputDescription = document.querySelector("#input-description").value;

    console.log("i am active");

    if(inputFirstname == "" || inputName == "" || inputGender == "" || inputDescription == "")
    {
        labelElementLabelsComplete.style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log("you're in the loop")
    }
});
```

Removing the form action, I can move to the next page using javascript but all the input data won't be send over.

```
    if(inputFirstname == "" || inputName == "" || inputGender == "" || inputDescription == "")
    {
        labelElementLabelsComplete.style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log("you're in the loop")
    }
    else
    {
        window.location = "personadded.php"
    }
```

Comment: You are using a **form** element so by default hitting submit should send the data to a PHP script. I'm not sure if that's the same file as your code here or not. Either way, you can choose to add some PHP code that processes the input fields and then redirects, or you can use AJAX to send the data and have javascript redirect you.

Comment: @EssXTee I'm going to put the PHP in the same file as the HTML. Can I do it without the form element? Will it still send the data over?

Comment: @EssXTee , if I remove the form and change the javascript loop I can load into the other page when all the labels have input but I don't know how to send the data from all the forms. I will update my question.

Comment: You should use event.preventDefault() on buttonElement.addEventListener("click",function() and fire form.sumbit() manually only if all validations passed successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to cover here so I'll try to make it all make sense.

First, if you want to submit the form to the same PHP file (I'll assume this page's filename is personadded.php), you can leave the 'action' attribute off. By default forms will submit to the same page.

Next, you will need some PHP code to process the data. Along with that, if any of the data is missing, you should display this form (I know javascript is used to validate, but we want PHP to also check just in case). So PHP will first validate that all the fields have a value. If they don't, PHP will display your form. If all of the fields do have a value, it will instead save to a database and redirect to the next page.

```
<?php

  $firstname = (!empty($_REQUEST["firstname"]) && $_REQUEST["firstname"] != "") ? $_REQUEST["firstname"] : false;
  $name = (!empty($_REQUEST["name"]) && $_REQUEST["name"] != "") ? $_REQUEST["name"] : false;
  $gender = (!empty($_REQUEST["gender"]) && $_REQUEST["gender"] != "") ? $_REQUEST["gender"] : false;
  $description = (!empty($_REQUEST["description"]) && $_REQUEST["description"] != "") ? $_REQUEST["description"] : false;

  // If any of the values passed from the form are blank/empty, display the form
  if(empty($firstname) || empty($name) || empty($gender) || empty($description)) {
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="assets-addperson/css/personstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Festive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Add a person</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pagesize">
            <h1>Create a new account</h1>
            <img src="assets-addperson/images/create_account.png" alt="create_account" class="image_account"/>

            <p class="text_labels_complete">Every field needs to be filled!</p>

            <form method="GET" id="form1">
                <div class="class-labels">
                    <label for="input-firstname">
                        First Name
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="input-firstname" name="firstname">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="input-name">
                        Name
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="input-name" name="name">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="input-gender">
                        Gender
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="input-gender" name="gender">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="input-description">
                        Description
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="input-description" name="description">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" class="create_account_button" value="Create Account">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="assets-addperson/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html><?php
  } else {
    // If we have all the values, you can process the form and redirect to another page

    // Code to save your fields to the database would be here

    header("Location: https://URL_TO_ANOTHER_PAGE_HERE");
    die();
  }
?>
```

I did not include code to save to the database because that is an entirely different question. What type of database you have matters, and then there are several methods PHP can use to save to a database, not to mention discussion around best practices. So for now, I am only answering the initial form submission part of your question, not how to save the form data to a database.

Lastly, with your javascript you will actually want to add an event listener to the form so that when it is submitted, you can stop the form from being submitted if not all of the fields are set. You can do this with the 'preventDefault()' function for an event. Basically, when any event is being processed, using 'preventDefault()' stops whatever action would normally happen (in this case, stop the form from being submitted).

```js
console.log("loaded");

var formElement = document.querySelector("#form1");
var labelElementLabelsComplete = document.querySelector(".text_labels_complete");

var inputFirstname;
var inputName;
var inputGender;
var inputDescription;

formElement.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    inputFirstname = document.querySelector("#input-firstname").value;
    inputName = document.querySelector("#input-name").value;
    inputGender = document.querySelector("#input-gender").value;
    inputDescription = document.querySelector("#input-description").value;

    console.log("i am active");

    if(inputFirstname == "" || inputName == "" || inputGender == "" || inputDescription == "") {
      labelElementLabelsComplete.style.visibility = "visible";
      console.log("you're in the loop")
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you, this should be able to help me further with my project. I'm currently creating the database so I can test it alongside with the code. I'll try to understand first and then implement!